# Formik Field - how to CSS format the inbuilt <input> component

Tags: formik

New to Formik. I am trying to CSS format the  field that will be emitted by Formik , but am coming up short. Is wrapping each Field with a  the right approach? I was hoping to pass a style attribute to  but it doesnt accept one.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `className="your-class"`, and then style the class as needed.

```
<Field
  className="main"
  type="number"
  name="numberInput"
  ... other props here ...
/>
```

will give you:

```
<input name="numberInput" class="main" type="number">
```